# Does ThreadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime() include time spent in all states, or just RUNNABLE?

Tags: java, multithreading, jmx

Like the topic says, does it include time spent in BLOCKED and WAITING etc, states as well, or is this just RUNNABLE? The docs just say "cpu time", which is a bit vague...

Comment: auu, so little interested at a reasonable question...

Answer (score 4):

ThreadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime() includes only the time spent in the RUNNABLE state, but note that the way this is calculated depends on the platform.

Here's a program that shows that getThreadCpuTime() covers only the time the thread is actually doing something:

```
import java.lang.management.*;

public class Test implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {

        long time = System.nanoTime();
        Test test = new Test();
        synchronized (test) {
            new Thread(test).start();
            while (test.cpu == -1) {
                test.wait();
                }
            }
        System.out.println("time: " + (System.nanoTime() - time));
        System.out.println("cpu: " + test.cpu);
        }

    private long cpu = -1;

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            ThreadMXBean thread = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
            long cpu = thread.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            Thread.sleep(300);
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            while (System.nanoTime() - time < 700000000);
            this.cpu = thread.getCurrentThreadCpuTime() - cpu;
            }
        catch (InterruptedException _) {}
        finally {
            notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this app prove your hypothesis?

Comment: It is not an hypothesis, I looked at the Java source code, which is how I discovered that it "depends on the platform".  Because it is difficult to show this research, I designed a test that, although it is not proving anything, shows the correlation.

Answer (score 1):

*Runnable only.* That's it, otherwise it'd be useless.

Comment: Not so. If it includes all time, the runnable time could be derived from total - blocked - waiting. Also, you haven't provided any proof of anything, you've just stated what looks like a guess.

Comment: if it did incl. blocking/waiting all threads started at the same time would have the same value. It's a pretty simple observation you could devise yourself. Alternatively check the source of JVM impl... Or if you need proof state if in the question. Morealso CPU time as its name suggests is the time has been spent within the CPU. BLOCKED/WAITING states lay dormant in the OS scheduler not the CPU, I truly thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is only `RUNNABLE`, you can receive further statistics of time spent in other states through [ThreadInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html) with the following methods:

- [getBlockedTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html#getBlockedTime%28%29)
- [getWaitedTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html#getWaitedTime%28%29)

There is no further discrimination between `TIMED_WAITING` and `WAITING` in `getWaitedTime()`.